# Push data into javascript object is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push data in to a Javascript object but I am unable to do it.

```
var obj = {};
if(cust_opt_title == "Size"){
    obj['Size'] = {'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'};
    obj['Size'].push({'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'}); // I tried this also
} else {
    obj['Color'] = {'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'};
    obj['Color'].push({'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'}); // I tried this also
}
```

I want output like this:

[image]

Comment: You can't `push()` in to an object, only arrays. To add data to an object, create a new property and assign a value to it

Comment: Try `obj['Size'] = [{...}]`

Comment: Current answers are having to assume what your goal is. It would help here if you could edit the question to show an example of the final object structure you want to achieve.

Comment: Why downvote always ? What's wrong in question?

Comment: Read my question. I already mentioned i tried that actions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an array, if not exists, before pushing a value.

[`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a method of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/).

```js
var obj = {},
    cust_opt_title = 'Size';

if (cust_opt_title === "Size") {
    obj['Size'] = obj['Size'] || [];
    obj['Size'].push({ custom_option_select_text: 'Red + $200.00' });
} else {
    obj['Color'] = { custom_option_select_text: 'Red + $200.00' };
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It's not push object. It's update object. When, Size condition true then Size element add. After When else condition true then only Color element display. Size element was removed.

Comment: That's what this answer is doing

Comment: what should when be removed?

Comment: Can you please create snippet of your answer. So, I can see here.

Comment: do you like to remove the same element? only objects which have the same object reference are same/identical objects. objects with same key/values look same but aren't.

Comment: Actually, should be working like that : if Size condition true that element added in obj. Then, second time else true, then Color element also added. Previous data should not be removed. Currently, previous data removed in this code.

Comment: `Color` should be an array, too? that does not match your picture, above.

Comment: @KevalMehta this answers your question perfectly as you have asked it.  If you have any other criteria you need to either update your question (for clarification) or ask a *new* question (if different from what has been asked and *correctly* answered).   In summary, make `obj['Size']` (and color) an array *first* before pushing any values to it and always treat it as an array.

Comment: Sorry @NinaScholz. It's not working :( Can you please create with fiddle. I think here it's always blank . => obj['Size'] = obj['Size'] || [];

Comment: I think in else condition i need to check like if obj['Color'] is not exist then only obj['Color'] create and push otherwise no create again and push.

Comment: please add this special use cases into the question along with the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

obj['size'] is not an array, so you can't push to it (you can only push to arrays). I see that you want to push multiple objects into the object properties and **I think you want them to be arrays, even if they stay empty**. so you need to **define them as arrays** first.

```
var obj = {
    'Size': [],
    'Color': []
};

if(cust_opt_title === "Size"){
    obj['Size'].push({'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'});
} else {
    obj['Color'].push({'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'});
}
```

By the way, the fact that I say that 'I think you want ...' means that your question wasn't clear enough.